# Pandas : A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I desesperatly look for help... I am stuck !
I can not figure out about the famous Pandas message :

df['ATR'][i]=(df['ATR'][i-1]*(n-1)+ df['TR'][i])/n

**/home/pi/Documents/cBot-Project/jarvis/jarvis_indicators.py:264: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame**

Is there anyone for helping me for the right syntax with .loc for my code in order to stop warning message ?

Thank you very much

HERE IS THE FULL CODE OF MY FUNCTION :

```
def jarvis_Supertrend2(d,factor=4,n=12): 

#Calculation of ATR
df=d.copy()
df['H-L']=abs(df['high']-df['low'])
df['H-PC']=abs(df['high']-df['close'].shift(1))
df['L-PC']=abs(df['low']-df['close'].shift(1))
df['TR']=df[['H-L','H-PC','L-PC']].max(axis=1)
df['ATR']=np.nan
df.loc[n-1,'ATR']=df['TR'][:n-1].mean() #.ix is deprecated from pandas verion- 0.19


for i in range(n,len(df)):
    df['ATR'][i]=(df['ATR'][i-1]*(n-1)+ df['TR'][i])/n

#Calculation of SuperTrend
df['Upper Basic']=(df['high']+df['low'])/2+(factor*df['ATR'])
df['Lower Basic']=(df['high']+df['low'])/2-(factor*df['ATR'])
df['Upper Band']=df['Upper Basic']
df['Lower Band']=df['Lower Basic']
for i in range(n,len(df)):
    if df['close'][i-1]<=df['Upper Band'][i-1]:
        df['Upper Band'][i]=min(df['Upper Basic'][i],df['Upper Band'][i-1])
    else:
        df['Upper Band'][i]=df['Upper Basic'][i]    
for i in range(n,len(df)):
    if df['close'][i-1]>=df['Lower Band'][i-1]:
        df['Lower Band'][i]=max(df['Lower Basic'][i],df['Lower Band'][i-1])
    else:
        df['Lower Band'][i]=df['Lower Basic'][i]   
df['SuperTrend']=np.nan
for i in df['SuperTrend']:
    if df['close'][n-1]<=df['Upper Band'][n-1]:
        df['SuperTrend'][n-1]=df['Upper Band'][n-1]
    elif df['close'][n-1]>df['Upper Band'][i]:
        df['SuperTrend'][n-1]=df['Lower Band'][n-1]
for i in range(n,len(df)):
    if df['SuperTrend'][i-1]==df['Upper Band'][i-1] and df['close'][i]<=df['Upper Band'][i]:
        df['SuperTrend'][i]=df['Upper Band'][i]
    elif  df['SuperTrend'][i-1]==df['Upper Band'][i-1] and df['close'][i]>=df['Upper Band'][i]:
        df['SuperTrend'][i]=df['Lower Band'][i]
    elif df['SuperTrend'][i-1]==df['Lower Band'][i-1] and df['close'][i]>=df['Lower Band'][i]:
        df['SuperTrend'][i]=df['Lower Band'][i]
    elif df['SuperTrend'][i-1]==df['Lower Band'][i-1] and df['close'][i]<=df['Lower Band'][i]:
        df['SuperTrend'][i]=df['Upper Band'][i]

# -- Drop all columns we do not need --
df.drop(columns=(['H-L','H-PC','L-PC','TR','ATR','Upper Basic','Lower Basic','Upper Band','Lower Band']), inplace=True)
# trend : Uptrend :True Dwntrend : False0
df['UpTrend'] =df['close']>=df['SuperTrend']  

return df
```

And warning messages :
See the caveats in the documentation:
df['ATR'][i]=(df['ATR'][i-1]*(n-1)+ df['TR'][i])/n
/tmp/ipykernel_12200/3973276324.py:22: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

df['Upper Band'][i]=min(df['Upper Basic'][i],df['Upper Band'][i-1])
/tmp/ipykernel_12200/3973276324.py:24: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

df['Upper Band'][i]=df['Upper Basic'][i]
/tmp/ipykernel_12200/3973276324.py:27: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

df['Lower Band'][i]=max(df['Lower Basic'][i],df['Lower Band'][i-1])
/tmp/ipykernel_12200/3973276324.py:29: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

df['Lower Band'][i]=df['Lower Basic'][i]
/tmp/ipykernel_12200/3973276324.py:33: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

df['SuperTrend'][n-1]=df['Upper Band'][n-1]
/tmp/ipykernel_12200/3973276324.py:38: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

df['SuperTrend'][i]=df['Upper Band'][i]
/tmp/ipykernel_12200/3973276324.py:40: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

df['SuperTrend'][i]=df['Lower Band'][i]
/tmp/ipykernel_12200/3973276324.py:42: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

df['SuperTrend'][i]=df['Lower Band'][i]
/tmp/ipykernel_12200/3973276324.py:44: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

df['SuperTrend'][i]=df['Upper Band'][i]

Comment: use df = df.copy(), basically that's a warning. If you change a working dataframe.

Comment: Thank you Wrench : but where in the formula ? df['ATR'][i]=(df['ATR'][i-1]*(n-1)+ df['TR'][i])/n

Comment: where you are creating new columns like 'ATR' of the df, use copy of it. Also for using ATR, EMA like indicators, you can use TA-Lib library

Comment: I add df=d.copy() in my function...but still have Warning

Comment: Thank you Wrench... but I don t understand : in the code :  df['ATR'][i]=(df['ATR'][i-1]*(n-1)+ df['TR'][i])    I use an existing column (ATR) created before ?